# Is there any way to Deploy Console application exe file into IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, console

I have one application, which is created using **asp .net** and it is deployed and working fine. Now, I want to **add one functionality to that application**. I created that functionality using **console application**. So, **How can I deploy that console application file into IIS and add to application**.

Please share your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Why console app? Why not class library?

Comment: Yeah i used class library with output type as console

Comment: if you created class library, put dll in bin folder. thats it

Comment: But that functionality includes scheduled task. it will work with dll?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Console Application. Use `IHttpModule` in your class library and it will be accessible with IIS.

If you really want to use a Console Application, you can *self host* your web application with the help of **[OWIN and Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana)**.